# Trying to use threading macros and getting error

Tags: clojure, macros

This is my first attempt at using the thread-first macro
My goal is to put the vector through `map` and then `filter`

```
(-> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
    (filter (fn [x] (<= x 3)))
    (map (fn [x] (* 10 x))))
```

I am getting

```
   Error: function (x){return (10 * x);
}is not ISeqable
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at cljs.core.seq
```

What does it mean?

Comment: you need to use `->>`

Comment: @cfrick why? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to use `->>`.  The doc:

> Threads the expr through the forms. **Inserts x as the
>     last item in the first form**, making a list of it if it is not a
>     list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
>     last item in second form, etc.

Your threaded calls there are `filter` and `map` which both take the list as second param. `->` puts them as first parameter. So your code there would look like this: `(filter [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] (fn [x] (<= x 3)))`, your function is no seq, hence the error.

Comment: As a slight side note: In CLJS and Clojure 1.7.0 you can use transducers which IMO simplify this: `(into [] (comp (filter ...) (map ...)) [1 2 3 4 5 6])`